# Send device token to mysqlPHP xCode Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

after i updated Xcode swift 2 this commands did work please help me

i was put link in appDelegate if user run app then will send to php to add in mysql but now did work on new Xcode version  like this command
var url:NSString = "http://wwww.maktoob.ga2h.com/Push/regsterID.php?deviceToken=(deviceTokenString)"

---- code below ---

```
let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet( charactersInString: "<>" )



    let deviceTokenString: String = ( deviceToken.description as NSString )

        .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet( characterSet )

        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "" ) as String



    print( deviceTokenString )



    var url:NSString = "http://wwww.maktoob.ga2h.com/Push/regsterID.php?deviceToken=\(deviceTokenString)"

    print("http://maktoob.ga2h.com/Push/regsterID.php?deviceToken=\(deviceTokenString)")



    url = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("", withString: "%20")

    url = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/n", withString: "%0A")

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url as String)!)

    var result = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Syntax?

Comment: the problem now its not work var url:NSString = "http://wwww.maktoob.ga2h.com/Push/regsterID.php?deviceToken=\(deviceTokenString)"
this command on swift 2 not work and not send to php